# Installing Linux over Windows 7

Tags: linux-mint, windows

I have a computer with three hard drives:

1. SSD with Windows 7 installed
2. HDD with Linux Mint installed
3. HDD with no OS, formatted as NTFS drive for storing files.

I have been using EasyBCD to dual boot, and when I am in Windows 7, I can only see drives 1 and 3. When I am in Linux Mint, I can only see drives 2 and 3.

I got a new computer, and want to install Linux Mint on the SSD, but I am having an issue.

I put Mint on a thumb drive with Universal USB Installer, and when I boot to the thumb drive, it can only see drives 2 and 3. I checked the 'DYI' partitioning section and drive 1 does not show up there either.

So, my question is, how can I make drive 1 visible when I am booting to the other drives so that I can install Mint over it?

edit: Here is where it gets really weird. When I try to wipe drive 1 (the SSD with Windows 7) DBAN doesn't register it